# Share artifacts between workflows / Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I know that you can share artifacts between jobs of the same workflow...

But how can I share artifacts across different workflows?

Comment: FYI this is now on the roadmap from what I can tell: https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/755

Answer (score 45, accepted):

GitHub has now added a [REST API for downloading artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#artifacts). Basically you do

```
GET repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/artifacts/{artifact_id}/{archive_format}
```

And then you'll have to look for `Location:` in the response, and then access that url to download the artifact. The url is valid for 1 minute.

There's a GitHub Action that uses the API above that you can easily add to your workflow. I use it like this

```
- name: Download artifact
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
  with:
    workflow: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.workflow_id }}
    workflow_conclusion: success
```

Read more about it here: https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact

Comment: Just noting that it's important to use this action and not the official github one - I did not realise at first that the Github download artifact action requires the artifact to be in the same workflow run

Comment: if the workflow is reusable, how do I setup the `with.workflow` ?

Answer (score 5):

The official [actions/download-artifact@v4](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) now supports this capability!

For those using [dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact), switching to actions/download-artifact@v4 is as easy as changing:

```
    - name: Download artifacts
      uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: my_artifact
        run_id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
```

to

```
    - name: Download artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: my_artifact
        run-id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
        github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

An example of a working commit that applied such changes (including switching from actions/upload-artifact@v3 to actions/upload-artifact@v4 in the other workflow) can be found [here](https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-md5sum/commit/83651765269bce97c16601f6a096e383b033fd43).

Pay attention to the fact that dawidd6/action-download-artifact uses `run_id` with an underscore whereas actions/download-artifact uses `run-id` with a dash. Also, `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` is an **automatically** generated token, so you don't need to do anything besides referencing it in the workflow.

Please refer to https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/blob/main/README.md#download-artifacts-from-other-workflow-runs-or-repositories as well as https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/3 if you need more details.

Comment: what if I want the `workflow_run.id` of a different run?  How can I download artifacts by PR number using `actions/download-artifact@v4`?

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to use [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) to share data between workflows, without the need for 3rd party actions.

For example: `microservice-A_pull_request.yml`

```yaml
on: workflow_run
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - ...

      - name: Test Functional
        run: make test-microservice-a-functional

      - name: Store code coverage file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: coveragemicroservicea-${{ github.sha }}
          path: coveragemicroservicea.out
```

And then `main.yml`:

```yaml
name: PR

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  microserviceAPR:
    uses: auth0/sandcastle/.github/workflows/microservice-A_pull_request.yml@master
    secrets: inherit
  microserviceBPR:
    uses: auth0/sandcastle/.github/workflows/microservice-B_pull_request.yml@master
    secrets: inherit
  coverage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [microserviceAPR, microserviceBPR]
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version-file: './go.mod'

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: coveragemicroservicea-${{ github.sha }}

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: coveragemicroserviceb-${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Merge coverage files
        id: getcoverage
        run: |
          output=$(make get-coverage) 
          echo "coverage=$output" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Comment on PR
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
             issue_number: context.issue.number,
             owner: context.repo.owner,
             repo: context.repo.repo,
             body: '${{ steps.getcoverage.outputs.coverage }}'
            })
```

Comment: this looks more like a comment, and yes, as others pointed out, that is an option too... Things have also evolved in the past 2 years and now you have reusable workflows and workflow calls that accept inputs

Comment: @Hitmands i posted this as an answer because it's the most up-to-date solution

Comment: I would love to see more context around this. I don't see who it's doable without using 3rd party https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact action at the time of writing. GitHub still has the issue to share artifacts between workflows open.

Comment: @demisx added code examples :)

Comment: I tried this using two different workflows, and it most definitely does not work.

Comment: This does work, but only if the dependent workflow fires on a `workflow_run` event. See [reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

Comment: Answer should be edited to explain in which circumstances this does currently work, as it does not address the general question.

Comment: this is for passing data from caller workflow to calling workflow as reuseable workflow inputs, but what about passing data from calling workflow (outputs) back to caller workflow ?

Comment: Changing `on: workflow_run` to `on: workflow_call` (or adding it) would allow that the artifact consumer workflow triggers the artifact producer (via the `use:`). I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77663335/6108874) @WoodyWoodsta @cmbuckley

Answer (score 2):

Probably not yet doable:

> After a workflow ends, you can download an archive of the uploaded artifacts on GitHub by finding the workflow run in the Actions tab. GitHub does not currently offer a REST API to retrieve uploaded artifacts.
>
> If you need to access artifacts from a previously run workflow, you'll need to store the artifacts somewhere. For example, you could run a script at the end of your workflow to store build artifacts on Amazon S3 or Artifactory, and then use the storage service's API to retrieve those artifacts in a future workflow.

https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/persisting-workflow-data-using-artifacts#sharing-data-between-workflow-runs

Answer (score 2):

What's possible is to trigger a workflow `wa` from another one `wb`, so that artifacts produced by `wa` can be accessed within `wb`. That's not exactly "sharing an artifact from one workflow to another", but running/reusing a workflow from another.

On 2021 Github launched [Reusable workflows](https://github.blog/2022-02-10-using-reusable-workflows-github-actions/), which allows to call a workflow from another one. Then artifacts can be easily "shared" with `actions/upload-artifact` and `actions/download-artifact`. As @WoodyWoodsta [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355925/share-artifacts-between-workflows-github-actions/77663335#comment134064848_60355925), maybe this will get improved/extended in [Actions: Artifact-based Deployments #755](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/755), to access artifacts from any workflow.

Here is an example of how a deploy workflow can depend/use a compile workflow and get its outcome:

`compile.yml` (artifact producer):

```yaml
name: 'Compile LaTeX'

on:
  # Reusable workflows (other workflows can trigger this)
  workflow_call:
  # Allows to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**' # '*' Matches zero or more characters, but does not match the `/` character. '**' matches zero or more of any character.
      - '!main' # main will trigger/reuse this workflow by other means (via workflow call)

jobs:
  compile:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - name: ' Checkout'
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v3'
        with:
          submodules: 'false'       # { false, true, recursive } default: false

      - name: ' Compile LaTeX document'
        uses: 'xu-cheng/latex-action@v3'
        with:
          root_file: 'main.tex'
          docker_image: 'ghcr.io/xu-cheng/texlive-full:20231201' # fixed texlive version, should match the one in devcontainer
          #latexmk_use_lualatex: true # disabled: driven by .latexmkrc
          args: '' # override default arguments and rely/honor on .latexmkrc
          post_compile: 'ls -la build' # just log build files

      - name: '⬆️ Upload artifact' # to share with other workflows
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: 'pdf'
          path: 'build/main.pdf'
```

`deploy.yml` (artifact consumer):

```yaml
name: Deploy PDF

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  # Allows to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  compile:
    # Reuse the compile workflow (can even point to another repo, see the docs)
    uses: ./.github/workflows/compile.yml

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Wait/depend on the compile job!
    needs: compile
    steps:
      - name:  Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: recursive       # { false, true, recursive } default: false

      - name: ⬇️ Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: pdf
          path: deploy

      - name:  Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.5
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: deploy   # The folder the action should deploy.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity.

I wanted to share some lightweight contextual strings amongst workflows and created this https://github.com/marcoslopes/git-notes-action.

My specific use-case was to have different workflows dealing with build and deploy.
Build would create an ami with packer and Deploy use that created image to be deployed with terraform.

As I am writing this I realise I could have added the sha as a tag on the image itself and search for it through the cli, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Use Github Cli to download artifacts.

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Github cli Bolivia
  env:
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  run: | # gh run download RUN_ID --name ARTIFACT_NAME
    gh run download 5268888888 --name downloader-artifact
    # Or use only --name when the name is unique, by example:
    gh run download --name downloader-artifact-version-1.2.3
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from explanation around how to retrieve the RUN_ID of a job of interest. Hardcoding it doesn't sound like a viable solution. However, thanks for demonstrating that this is a possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the related feature issue is [download-artifact/issues#3](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/3), which [references](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/3#issuecomment-828965675) the [dawidd6/action-download-artifact](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact) action that @Tobbe mentions in his accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355925/share-artifacts-between-workflows-github-actions/65049722) above.