# What is Github Action's equivalent of Azure DevOps release

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, github-actions

In Azure DevOps, there are separate pipelines for Build and Releases. Single build (build artifacts) can be released to multiple environment with different triggers.

E.g. when build is comoleted, it triggers release to Test env. When it is approved, release to another env with different parameters is triggered.

What's the GitHubs way of deploying single build artifacts to multiple environments?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no direct equivalent.

It can be modeled using multiple github actions or multiple dependent jobs in the same action. But it's not the same thing.

Some folks have been very creative with the build action creating an Issue and waiting for a LGTM comment from specific other people to trigger a new action. You can use releases or packages to store the build output.

I guessing something will come in the future, but for now, if you want environments, stages, approvals etc. Then keep using Azure Pipelines with GitHub.

Comment: Is it possible to share build artifacts across multiple workflows?

Comment: If you create a GitHub Release, you can attach files to that. If you zip 'm all up in a supported package type, you can stick 'm in GitHub Packages. You can even attach them to an Issue if they're below the max attachment size. But there is no Pipeline Attachment equivalent yet across actions. You can use the `actions/upload-artifact` and `actions/download-artifact` actions in the same action across jobs.

Comment: Some people are beginning to build tasks that can do what you're after, but they rely on knowing the previous workflow's `id`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355925/share-artifacts-between-workflows-github-actions