# GitHub Actions: pass data from workflow to another workflow?

Tags: github-actions

GitHub Actions allows to trigger a workflow from another workflow using the `workflow_run` event as per this documentation: [Events that trigger workflows - Webhook Events - workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)

This works fine. However, for the situations I am planning to use this all workflows except for the first one would likely rely on some information about the previous workflow... E.g. certain strings / conditionals / etc...

**How can we pass *data* from one workflow to another?**

Is there some reference similar to the `needs.jobs.<job_id>.*` which can be used to pass data from one job to another?

**NOTE**: Using an *artifact* built in workflow A from within workflow B is a different question (asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355925/share-artifacts-between-workflows-github-actions)), which can be solved by using the following action: `dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2`

Comment: Did you try using a repository_dispatch trigger? With it, you can send a dispatch event from a workflow to start another one, sending some datas through the request payload.

Comment: Using `repository_dispatch` seems to be targeted at other situations. Since there is the `workflow_run` event specifically for my purpose I'd rather use that instead of building in a wacky workaround...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm also in a similar sitation where repository_dispatcher doesn't quite seem to be the correct method since I'm not for a "trigger" option but rather use the output (data) from another workflow.

Comment: @Fashinated, It has been a while and I think eventually we solved this some other way... sorry for not having a good answer, IIRC the answer below was still the best option at the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [repository_dispatch action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/repository-dispatch) to send an event that contains the data you need. Then it will trigger another workflow that has `on: repository_dispatch` and a specific event name. Check the documentation of the action for more information.

You can pass the data you want inside `client-payload`. For bigger files I suppose artifacts can be used.

For example, you have your first workflow:

```
name: Test

on:
  - push
jobs:
  preflight-job:
    name: First Step
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Repository Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          event-type: my-event
          client-payload: '{"ref": "${{ github.ref }}", "sha": "${{ github.sha }}", "test": "test message"}'
```

And then create another workflow file that will be triggered by this event:

```
name: Repository Dispatch
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [my-event]
jobs:
  myEvent:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.client_payload.ref }}
          
      - run: echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.sha }}
      - run: echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.test }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I would like to ask if there are any security concern/known issues to use this action?