# Using GitHub Actions and two separate .yml file ci/cd, how do I push the packed packages to GitHub packages?

Tags: yaml, nuget, github-actions

Within the ci.yml I am packing the projects

```yaml
- name: Create Client Package
  run: dotnet pack ${{ env.CLIENT_NAME }} --no-build --configuration ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} --output ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}

- name: Create Model Package
  run: dotnet pack ${{ env.MODEL_NAME }} --no-build --configuration ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} --output ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}

- name: Create NBS Package
  run: dotnet pack ${{ env.NBS_NAME }} --no-build --configuration ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} --output ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}

- name: Upload NuGet Packages
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  if: ${{ matrix.language == 'csharp' && (github.event.pull_request.merged || github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch') }}
  with:
    name: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}-nuget
    path: ${{ env.NUGET_PATH }}/*.nupkg
```

How do I find these files created from the cd.yml file so I can push to the GitHub Packages?

```yaml
- name: Download NuGet Packages from GitHub
  uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2.13.0
  with:
    workflow: ci.yml
    workflow_conclusion: success
    name: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}-nuget
    path: ${{ env.NUGET_PATH }}/output
    search_artifacts: true

- name: Push NuGet Packages to GitHub Packages
  run: dotnet nuget push ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}/*.nupkg --source github --skip-duplicate --api-key ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_PAT }}
```

I tried packing the projects in the ci.yml file and reference their location using `env.PUBLISH_PATH`

When it is run the location does not exist.

Now using the upload/download of artifacts I am able to access the NuGet packages. But am unable to `PUSH` the packages to the GitHub Packages.
I get an error of `warn : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.`
I have tried the GITHUB_TOKEN and creating a PAT that has read/write/delete access to the packages. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github actions share workspace/artifacts between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498605/github-actions-share-workspace-artifacts-between-jobs)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355925/share-artifacts-between-workflows-github-actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using for the cd.yml file

```yaml
 - name: Add GitHub Packages nuget source
   run: dotnet nuget add source --username ${{ github.actor }} --password ${{ secrets.PACKAGES_PAT }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository_owner }}/index.json"
 - uses: actions/checkout@v3
 - name: Setup .NET
   uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
   with:
     dotnet-version: 6.0.x

 # https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact
 - name: Download NuGet Packages from GitHub
   uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2.13.0
   with:
     workflow: ci.yml
     workflow_conclusion: success
     name: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}-nuget
     path: ${{ env.NUGET_PATH }}/output
     search_artifacts: true

 - name: Push NuGet Packages to GitHub Packages
   run: dotnet nuget push ${{ env.NUGET_PATH }}/output/*.nupkg --source github --skip-duplicate --api-key ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Used `secret.PACKAGES_PAT` for the add source but used `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` for the push function.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm the following:
The dotnet pack commands in your jobs are actually creating the .nupkg files in the directory specified by ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }}.

The ${{ env.PUBLISH_PATH }} environment variable in your CI/CD environment is correctly set to the directory where the .nupkg files are generated.

Comment: When I run both the pack and the push commands in the same job, ci.yml, it works fine. When I move the push to the cd.yml it does not find anything.